# Best Practice - Format Numbered List Output - PowerShell

Tags: powershell

## Use Case

The following code lists the current User Accounts with SID values on the localhost

Outputting the format to a output numbered list will not separate values in a table

What is best practice to code a readable formatted output

## Code

```
$sid = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().groups
$accounts = $sid.Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]).value

$hash = @{"sid"=$sid.value;"Accounts"=$accounts}

$obj = New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property $hash

for ($i=0; $i -lt $obj.sid.Length; $i++) 
{"{0:D2}. {1}  -   {2}" -f ($i),$obj.Accounts[$i],$obj.sid[$i]}
```

## Output

```
00. Everyone  -   S-1-1-0
01. NT AUTHORITY\Local account and member of Administrators group  -   S-1-5-114
02. BUILTIN\Administrators  -   S-1-5-32-544
03. BUILTIN\Remote Desktop Users  -   S-1-5-32-555
04. BUILTIN\Remote Management Users  -   S-1-5-32-580
05. BUILTIN\Performance Log Users  -   S-1-5-32-559
06. BUILTIN\Users  -   S-1-5-32-545
07. NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE  -   S-1-5-4
08. CONSOLE LOGON  -   S-1-2-1
09. NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users  -   S-1-5-11
10. NT AUTHORITY\This Organization  -   S-1-5-15
11. MicrosoftAccount\sumeet.singhji@outlook.com  -   S-1-11-96-3623454863-58364-18864-2661722203-1597581903-1914428568-11352006
56-1295981414-3729554605-567089576
12. NT AUTHORITY\Local account  -   S-1-5-113
13. LOCAL  -   S-1-2-0
14. NT AUTHORITY\Cloud Account Authentication  -   S-1-5-64-36
```

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing at all wrong with [Martin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50643509/311288). However, if the goal is to allow someone running the script to select a user, then I am a fan of `Out-Gridview` ([requires a GUI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-gridview?view=powershell-7.1)):

```
$list = for ($i=0; $i -lt $obj.sid.Length; $i++) 
{
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        SID = $obj.sid[$i]
        Accounts = $obj.Accounts[$i]
    }   
}
$selected = $list | Out-Gridview -PassThru
Write-Host ('You selected {0} - {1}' -f $selected.Accounts, $selected.SID)
```

Comment: Both your additions have been helpfull. One thing I would like to ask is. I already have the object $obj, which is the same as $list besides the noteproperty being an array vs array of objects. Wouldnt it be possible, easier to convert $obj to outgrid view? kind of like $list = [array]$obj.sid | out-gridview -passthru.

Comment: Note: `Out-GridView` requires a GUI and is therefore not available on **Windows Server Core** or **Windows Nano Server**. [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-gridview?view=powershell-7.1)

Answer (score 4):

I would create a list of objects with the two properties (SID and Account):

```
$list = for ($i=0; $i -lt $obj.sid.Length; $i++) 
{
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        SID = $obj.sid[$i]
        Accounts = $obj.Accounts[$i]
    }   
}
```

Then you get a nice output by just otuput the `$list`:

```
SID                                           Accounts                        
---                                           --------                                
S-1-1-0                                       Everyone                        
S-1-5-32-544                                  BUILTIN\Administrators          
S-1-5-32-559                                  BUILTIN\Performance Log Users   
S-1-5-32-545                                  BUILTIN\Users                   
S-1-5-4                                       NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE        
S-1-2-1                                       CONSOLE LOGON                   
S-1-5-11                                      NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users
S-1-5-15                                      NT AUTHORITY\This Organization  
S-1-2-0                                       LOCAL
```